# How to add new div after over anoter div in CSS?

Tags: css

Hi i am using this code.....

But when i add new div .myContainer after it is comes up. If i use clear both it not working.

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#navi,
#infoi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#infoi {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navi">a</div>
  <div id="infoi">
    <img src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" height="20" width="32" />b
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myContainer">
  ABCDEFGHICJLMNOP
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, how does it look in yours?

Comment: if i use "clear:both" property with ".myContainer" class it's not work